# Inverse Z transform of $\frac{z^{2}}{(z-1)^{3}}$

Tags: signal-processing, z-transform

The Question is given like this
Find the inverse Z transform of

> $$X(z)=\frac{z^{2}}{(z-1)^{3}}$$

**Attempt:**
$$\frac{X(z)}{z}=\frac{z}{(z-1)^{3}}=\frac{A}{(z-1)}+\frac{B}{(z-1){2}}+\frac{c}{(z-1){3}}$$
        after solving A=0,B=1,C=1
$$\frac{X(z)}{z}=\frac{1}{(z-1){2}}+\frac{1}{(z-1){3}}$$
$$X(z)=\frac{z^{-1}}{(1-z^{-1})^{2}}+\frac{z^{-2}}{(1-z^{-1})^{3}}$$
Then taking its inverse Z transform we get 
$$X(n)=nu(n)+\frac{(n-1)^{2}}{{2}}u(n-1)$$
**BUT**

the exact ans i am getting from all different method is

> $$\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

Whats is the mistake i am doing in this partial fraction method?

PS: I got the ans of this question from all possible method like **convlution method**,**residue method**,etc so plz help me with only partial fraction method as i already know other method.

Comment: I am not sure that your decomposition is correct. Indeed, if A=0, B=1 and C=1, then 
$$\dfrac{1}{(z-1)^2} + \dfrac{1}{(z-1)^3} = \dfrac{z}{(z-1)^3} \neq \dfrac{z^2}{(z-1)^3}$$

Comment: Yes You are saying right but I tried alot I am not getting help me to get the exact decomposition @JejeBelfort

Comment: I dont think you can decompose it further. I guess you have to work directly on $$\dfrac{z^2}{(z-1)^3} = \dfrac{z^{-1}}{(1-z^{-1})^3} $$

Comment: I am not getting how to work directly on that.but i saw many textbook do like my method by decomposition.actullly i got the solution by residue method without decompostion...but i want with this method@JejeBelfort

Comment: if i work directly on that i will get $$\frac{n^2}{2}$$. that is not matching with the ans @JejeBelfort

Comment: where is Region of Convergence (ROC)?

Comment: Actually the original question is given like this y(n)=$\sum_{k=-infinity}^n g(k)$ and the g(n)=nu(n), and y(-1)=0 given so i got directly the Y(z)=$\frac{z^{2}}{(z-1)^{3}}$ i did not know how to take roc of this signal so considered it a right sided signal and calculated now see if you can Help with this @k.Vijay

Comment: so why do you need to find out $Y(z)$?

Comment: Because after getting Y(z) then i can take its inverse z transform to get the y(n) expression to get my answer,actually I don't need to find Y(z) i can do it directly without Z transform and i already solved it without z transform.But i want to do it with z transform also i already solved it with variours other method of z transform but when i am doing it with partial fraction method i not getting the same answer.Please help me no one has given me the answer yet what mistake i am doing.@k.Vijay

Answer (score 0):

Good question to ask

$$X(z) = \frac{z^{-1}}{(1-z^{-1})^3}$$

$$(1-x)^{-n} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{n+k-1}{k}x^k$$

Only when $$|x| < 1$$

$$(1-\frac{1}{z})^{-3} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{k+2}{k}(\frac{1}{z})^k$$

$$Y(z) = (1-\frac{1}{z})^{-3}$$

$$Y(z) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{k+2}{k}(z)^{-k}$$

$$y(n) \rightleftharpoons Y(z)$$

$$y(n) = \binom{n+2}{n} u(n)$$

$$y(n) = \binom{n+2}{2} u(n)$$

$$X(z) = z^{-1} Y(z)$$

$$x(n) = y(n-1)$$

$$x(n) = \binom{n+1}{2} u(n-1)$$

$$x(n) = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}u(n-1)$$